# Автоматические действия с объектом при выбрасывании exception php

Tags: php

Возможно ли в PHP сделать нечто такое с объектом, чтобы при выбрасывании из него Exception'a с ним производились манипуляции?
Например, пусть есть некоторый класс **ValidatorHandler**:

```
class ValidatorHandler{
   private $validators = null;
   public function __construct(){
      $this->validators = new \SplObjectStorage();
   }
   public function doValidate(){
      foreach($this->validators as $validator){
         throw new \Exception('message', code);
      }
   }
   /**
   * Методы добавления/удаления новых валидаторов,
   * например attach && detach
   */
}
```

И есть класс, который работает с этим **ValidatorHandler**, допустим **SomeActions**:

```
class SomeActions{
   private $vh = null;
   public function __construct(){
      $this->vh = new ValidatorHandler();
   }
   public function handleAction($params){
      $this->vh->attach(new IValidator($params));
      /** и еще несколько, если будет угодно */
      try{
         $this->vh->doValidate();
      } catch (\Exception $e){
        /**
        * И вот в этом моменте можно было
        * бы почистить данные внутри ValidatorHandler,
        * но, это надо ручками писать в каждом вот таком вот try/catch
        */
        return $e->getMessage();
      }
   }
}
```

Поскольку я работаю с сокет-сервером (на основе Ratchet), то данные у меня  там внутри **ValidatorHandler** сохраняются, и при каждом вылете Exception'a, если их не чистить, они остаются там и будут валидироваться на разных коммандах, которые я выполняю (т.е. даже тогда, когда добавленные ранее валидаторы уже не нужны).

Существует ли механизм, с помощью которого можно было бы написать очистку коллекции в одном месте, чтобы она срабатывала при каждом выбросе Exception'a?

Comment: сложно что ли одну строку написать вида `$this->vh->cleanUp()` ?

Comment: @teran нет, написать не сложно, но обрабатываемых действий может быть много и в каждой прийдется это писать, а это уже много, а если что-то нужно будет изменить в блоке catch с этими действиями? придется потом еще раз переписывать в каждом блоке, а это еще действия и бонусом - возможность провтыкать где-то изменение...

Comment: А зачем исключение при валидации? Валидация должна проверять и рапортовать о том прошло или нет валидацию значения, и в случае если нет то возвращать описание чего и почему.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov такова логика приложения. В моем случае - надо терминировать выполнение и выбрасывать ошибку. Спасибо за замечание ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого магического метода нет.

В качестве решения можно сделать функцию в классе которая будет возвращать \Exception, и перед ретурном выполнять все необходимые чистки.

```
protected function exception($message, $code)
{
    // Очистка
    return new \Exception($message, $code);
}
```

И вызывать ее так:

```
throw $this->exception('message', code);
```

Если в коде класса возможны внешние ошибки отлавливать их в try и возвращать свой Exception через функцию.

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо. Я еще думал сделать так:
обернуть выброс ошибки внутри функции в *try/catch* и выбрасывать из внутреннего *catch* ошибку, предварительно очистив данные.